# pairwise addition in neon

Tags: arm, simd, neon, cortex-a

I want to add `00` and `01` indices value of `int64x2_t` vector in neon .
I am not able to find any pairwise-add instruction which will do this functionality .

```
int64x2_t sum_64_2;
//I am expecting result should be.. 
//int64_t result = sum_64_2[0] + sum_64_2[1];
```

- Is there any instruction in neon do to this logic.

Answer (score 0):

You can write it in two ways. This one explicitly uses the NEON `VADD.I64` instruction:

```
int64x1_t f(int64x2_t v)
{
  return vadd_s64 (vget_high_s64 (v), vget_low_s64 (v));
}
```

and the following one relies on the compiler to correctly select between using the NEON and general integer instruction sets. GCC 4.9 does the right thing in this case, but other compilers may not.

```
int64x1_t g(int64x2_t v)
{
  int64x1_t r;
  r=vset_lane_s64(vgetq_lane_s64(v, 0) + vgetq_lane_s64(v, 1), r, 0);
  return r;
}
```

When targeting ARM, the code generation is efficient. For AArch64, extra instructions are used, but the compiler could do better.

Comment: is there any difference between int64x1_t and int64 variable . as per your answer can I write like this `:int64_t result = f(v) //as per your answer`

Comment: They ought to be different. Effectively, it is a bug that GCC allows that, but it would break too much existing code to change now. However, other compilers and the AArch64 backend of GCC do not allow it, so it is best avoided, and the `vget_lane_s64`/`vset_lane_s64` intrinsics should be used to convert between int64x1_t and int64_t.

Comment: Thanks Charles Baylis for your reply .But still I am not satisfy with the result that I am getting with your logic .sorry for that .May be I am doing something wrong .I am asking one different question with NEON issue wrt same implementation .If possible please update your answer .

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30328555/warning-format-ld-expects-argument-of-type-long-int-but-argument-has-type

Comment: It looks like you have the wrong format string in that question - you need %lld for 64 bit values. The answer posted by werewindle is correct.